One series per \pstart in reledmac/reledpar
I am working on my dissertation on LyX and I am using reledpar to have the translation of the text on the right pages and the text itself on the left pages. The text is composed of approximately 90 different poems and because of that, I needed an apparatus criticus for each poem. I managed to do so and the series of critical notes renews itself every five series (A, B, C, D, E), so it starts back at series A.
The only problem I have (or at least the only problem I am noticing so far) is that the series flow regularly until they restart. By this, I mean that whenever there is a "sixth" series (6, 11 etc.) the order of the apparatus critici is off. There are no other error messages, so I cannot understand why this happens.
In the MWE that I provided this problem occurs on the first page. Still, with my thesis file, as I said, it occurs whenever the series restart (I don't know if it can be linked to the length of the text as well, and I can't perfectly reproduce the length of the text and the apparatus in the MWE).
Here is what I mean:

Here's the code:
    %% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass[12pt,italian]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[series={A,B,C,D,E},parapparatus,noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\lineation{pstart}
\linenummargin{outer}
\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B,C,D,E]
\Xsymlinenum[A,B,C,D,E]{|}
\Xnolemmaseparator
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}
\Xafterrule{0pt}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\AtEveryPend{\vskip1\baselineskip}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}



 %This is something that I simply copied and pasted from another question here
\makeatletter% We need to use command with @
  % Two counters: one for left and one for right
  \newcounter{mynotelevel}%
    \renewcommand{\themynotelevel}{\Alph{mynotelevel}}% Print the counter as a letter

  % Following lines are called at each \pstart
  \AtEveryPstartCall{%
          \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
          \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%No more than E series (5)
            \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}%If more than J => restart to A (1)
          }{}%
            \global\letcs{\nota}{\themynotelevel footnote}%And let mynote be equal to <X>footnote, where <X> is the current level \letcs is defined by etoolbox which called by reledmac

  }
  % This code is called when beginnings of each pstart are printed
  \AtEveryPstart{%
        \addtocounter{mynotelevel}{1}%Step counter
        \ifnumequal{\arabic{mynotelevel}}{6}{%No more than E series (5)
          \setcounter{mynotelevel}{1}}{}%% If more than E => restart to A (1)
          \seriesatend{\themynotelevel}% The series should be at the end
   }

\makeatother
    
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{babel}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pages}\begin{Leftside}\beginnumbering\pstart\textbf{\edtext{1}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{1}}} – First poem (A notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneA}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoA}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeA}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourA}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveA}}
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{2}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{2}}} – Second poem (B notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneB}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoB}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeB}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourB}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveB}}
    
    .\pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{3}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{3}}} – Third poem (C notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneC}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoC}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeC}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourC}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveC}}
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{4}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{4}}} – Fourth poem (D notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneD}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoD}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeD}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourD}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveD}}
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{5}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{5}}} – Fifth poem (E notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneE}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoE}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeE}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourE}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveE}}
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{6}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{6}}} – Sixth poem (A\textsuperscript{2} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneA\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoA\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeA\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourA\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveA\textsuperscript{2}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{7}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{7}}} – Seventh poem (B\textsuperscript{2} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneB\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoB\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeB\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourB\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveB\textsuperscript{2}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{8}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{8}}} – Eighth poem (C\textsuperscript{2} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneC\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoC\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeC\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourC\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveC\textsuperscript{2}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{9}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{9}}} – Ninth poem (D\textsuperscript{2} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneD\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoD\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeD\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourD\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveD\textsuperscript{2}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{10}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{10}}} – Tenth poem (E\textsuperscript{2} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneE\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoE\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeE\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourE\textsuperscript{2}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveE\textsuperscript{2}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \pstart\textbf{\edtext{11}{\lemma{}\nota[nonum]{\textbf{11}}} – Eleventh poem (A\textsuperscript{3} notes)}\skipnumbering
    
    Line \edtext{one}{\nota{note oneA\textsuperscript{3}}}
    
    Line \edtext{two}{\nota{note twoA\textsuperscript{3}}}
    
    Line \edtext{three}{\nota{note threeA\textsuperscript{3}}}
    
    Line \edtext{four}{\nota{note fourA\textsuperscript{3}}}
    
    Line \edtext{five}{\nota{note fiveA\textsuperscript{3}}}.
    
    \pend
    
    \endnumbering
    
    \end{Leftside}
    
    \begin{Rightside}
    
    \beginnumbering
    
    \numberlinefalse
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{1 – First translation}
    
    First translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{2 – Second translation}
    
    Second translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{3 – Third translation}
    
    Third translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{4 – Fourth translation}
    
    Fourth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{5 – Fifth translation}
    
    Fifth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{6 – Sixth poem}
    
    Sixth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{7 – Seventh poem}
    
    Seventh translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{8 – Eighth poem}
    
    Eighth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{9 – Ninth poem}
    
    Ninth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{10 – Tenth poem}
    
    Tenth translation
    
     \pend
    
    \pstart
    
    \textbf{11 – Eleventh poem}
    
    Eleventh translation
    
     \pend
    
    \endnumbering
    
    \end{Rightside}
    
    \end{pages}
    
    \Pages
    \end{document}

I don't know if I'm missing something extremely obvious, and I've looked for similar questions without any luck.
Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

An intriguing setup and question! Just for clarification: Do you plan, or expect, to ever have 6 or more poems one one page? This would be a problem for the approach of redefining the 6th series as the 1st series (the two apparati would collapse) – or for reledmac at large, which can handle 5 series at most.

With that said, another approach could be to "name" the series on a per-page basis, i.e. have the counter auto-reset to 1 (\Afootnote) on page break. Sometimes, this name change would occur mid-poem, but you wouldn't notice if you keep using your custom command \nota. -- The package perpage does just that: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/perpage. -- Just a suggestion, which unfortunately I don't know how to implement myself.

@marquinho Thanks! No, I don't plan on having more than 5 poems on one page; there are some sections with shorter poems but that hasn't happened in the whole document, and that's why I don't understand why the code found here: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/4-reledpar_one_series_per_pstart.pdf won't work properly. Unfortunately I definitely don't have the knowledge to make the perpage package "talk" to reledmac in the way I need it, but I will keep on trying!

Thanks for the pointer. I went to the example file and it turns out that their approach really is flawed! Take that example code, shorten the paragraphs a bit until you have 6 paragraphs on one page, and see how A1 and A2 series collapse. Both A series (line numbers 1 and 25, say) are together at the bottom of the apparatus after series E. The approach is buggy, you may want to file an issue on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac
